# can't get pm2 exit or stop event in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, pm2

1. i am using pm2 for keep server start in nodeJS
2. code uploaded on server and run command **pm2 start app.js --name appName**
3. but in some case when get error in code or something else, pm2 was stop OR kill all processes
4. at that time i want to send mail that the **pm2 process was stop OR kill**
5. i am using pm2.connect in app.js but cant't get event whenever pm2 stop OR kill, here is the code

   ```
   var pm2 = require('pm2');

   pm2.connect(function() {
      pm2.launchBus(function(err, bus) {
         bus.on('process:event', function(data) {
            console.log('IN APP ===>', data.event);
            Logger.info("IN APP ====> ", data.event);
            if (data.event === "exit") {
               console.log('IN APP exit', data.event);
               Logger.info("IN APP exit ====> ", data.event);
            }
       });
     });
   });
   ```

> with this code i am not able to get any event when pm2 was STOP or kill

Comment: i am getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can listen on node process events, and register call back function, please check the below code.

**Ps: you must run `process.exit();` inside callback function inorder to close the app **

You can call `process.exit();` instead send mail call back

```
function cb () {
    // Do stuff 
    // Send email 

     process.exit();

 }

 //do something when app is closing
 process.on('exit', cb );

  //catches ctrl+c event
  process.on('SIGINT', cb );

   // catches "kill pid" (for example: nodemon restart)
   process.on('SIGUSR1', cb );
   process.on('SIGUSR2', cb );

   process
       .on('uncaughtException', err => {
         console.error(err, 'Uncaught Exception thrown');
          process.exit(1);
         });
```